# Tester Logins and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We would like to be able to create a url and controller to handle direct login to our webapp without going through our current authentication scheme for testing/automation purposes. i.e. /testLogin?username=user&password=pass and now user is authenticated for the webapp. We are using spring 3.0.7 and spring security 3.1.3 so we can't use a spring profile for our dev environments to create a custom authentication scheme. Is there anything else I can do? Please let me know if I can clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do this because you don't want the URL to be exposed to the public when you deploy your application to production. You could create a form on an external site:

```
<form action="https://dev.example.com/app-context/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="j_username" value="user"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="j_password" value="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In with user"/>
</form>
```

Of course this will not work if you enable CSRF protection in Spring Security 3.2+ (as you should have enabled).